# Load/Store to specific mip level in vulkan compute shader

Tags: glsl, vulkan, compute-shader, mipmaps

As the title suggests, I want to read and write to a specific pixel of a certain mip level in a compute shader. I know on the Vulkan side, that I can specify how much mip levels I want to address in an ImageView, but I'm not sure how this works in glsl. Can I use a single image3D with a single ImageView:

```
layout(binding = 0, rgb8) uniform image3D img;
```

or do I need one image2D per mip level and thus multiple ImageViews?

```
layout(binding = 0, rgb8) uniform image2d mipLvl0;
layout(binding = 1, rgb8) uniform image2d mipLvl1;
layout(binding = 2, rgb8) uniform image2d mipLvl2;
```

Since both imageLoad/Store have an overload taking an `ivec3` I assume I can specify the mip level as the z coordinate in the first case.

Comment: mip levels, and 3D or arrays are two different things.

Comment: Maybe I chose my words poorly. What I meant to ask is, is there a possibility to access mip levels in a compute shader like an 3D image?

Comment: @BassGuru: What do you mean by "like an[sic] 3D image"? 3D images have consistent dimensions for all of the 2D depth slices. 2D mipmaps are smaller with every mipmap level. Since you access them by pixel sizes, you can't be unaware of which mipmap level you're accessing.

Comment: But you can get the image size via e.g. imageSize and calculate the dimension by subsequent halving it, or passing it indirectly by issuing a vkCmdDispatch for each level, adjusting the group count and pass the level via push constant

Comment: @BassGuru: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here. The mipmap levels of an image object are distinct images. The depths of a mipmap level of a 3D image object are all part of the same image. What you want isn't possible the way you want it and it doesn't really make sense to do it that way. What are you trying to do that you feel like you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot treat a mipmap pyramid as a single bound descriptor.

You can however bind each mipmap in a pyramid to an *arrayed* descriptor:

```
layout(binding = 0, rgb8) uniform image2d img[3];
```

This descriptor would be arrayed, meaning that `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount` for binding 0 of this set would be 3 in this example. You also would have to bind each mipmap of the image to a different array index in the descriptor, so `descriptorCount` and `pImageInfo` for that descriptor would need to provide multiple images for the `vkUpdateDescriptorSet` call. And the number of array elements needs to be stated in the shader, so it can't dynamically change (though you can leave some of them unspecified in the descriptor if your shader doesn't access them).

Also, you have to follow your implementation's rules for indexing an array of opaque types. Most desktop implementations allow these to be dynamically uniform expressions (and you need to activate the `shaderStorageImageArrayDynamicIndexing` feature), so you can use `uniform` variables rather than a constant expression. But the expressions cannot be arbitrary; they must resolve to the same value within a single draw call.

Also, using an array of images doesn't bypass the limits on the number of images a shader can use. However, most desktop hardware is pretty generous with these limits.